# Django: Update/edit populated form and formset

Tags: django, forms, view, formset

Can someone help me answering why my update view function doesn't run? It returns populated form and formset with no error messages (and without file attachments).

This happened after updating the function with a formset (made with modelformset_factory):

```
def recipe_update(request, id=None):
if request.method == 'GET':
    instance = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=id, user=request.user)
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    formset = IngredientModelFormset(queryset=Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe=instance))
elif request.method == 'POST':
    instance = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=id, user=request.user)
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    formset = IngredientModelFormset(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        recipe = form.save()
        for forms in formset:
            ingredient = forms.save(commit=False)
            ingredient.recipe = recipe
            ingredient.save()
        return redirect(recipe.get_absolute_url())
context = {
    "instance": instance,
    "form": form,
    'formset': formset,
}
return render(request, "recipes/recipe_form.html", context)
```

The create function is working correctly:

```
def recipe_create(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    formset = IngredientModelFormset(queryset=Ingredient.objects.none())
elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    formset = IngredientModelFormset(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        recipe = form.save()
        for forms in formset:
            ingredient = forms.save(commit=False)
            ingredient.recipe = recipe
            ingredient.save()
        return redirect(recipe.get_absolute_url())
context = {
    "form": form,
    'formset': formset,
}
return render(request, "recipes/recipe_form.html", context)
```

Thanks a lot!

**Update**

I changed the code according to the suggestions, which now gives me the following error: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

I am using the management_form in the template:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for forms in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">
    <div class="col-2">
        <label>{{ forms.name.label }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <div class="input-group">
            {{ forms.name }}
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-success add-form-row">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the updated views code:

```
def recipe_update(request, id=None):
  instance = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=id, user=request.user)
  form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
  formset = IngredientModelFormset(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
  if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    recipe = form.save()
    recipe.user = request.user
    recipe.save()
    for forms in formset:
        ingredient = forms.save(commit=False)
        ingredient.recipe = recipe
        ingredient.save()
    return redirect(recipe.get_absolute_url())
  context = {
    "instance": instance,
    "form": form,
    'formset': formset,
  }
  return render(request, "recipes/recipe_form.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet). And inside update view you need to pass instance argument for post request also:

```
def recipe_update(request, id=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        instance = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=id, user=request.user)   
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        formset = IngredientModelFormset(queryset=Ingredient.objects.none(), instance=instance)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        instance = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=id, user=request.user)
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
        formset = IngredientModelFormset(request.POST, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
```

Also you don't need to check request type with `request.POST or None` shortcut. You can simple rewrite your code to this:

```
def recipe_update(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Recipe, id=id, user=request.user)  
    form = RecipeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    formset = IngredientModelFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - now it is actually saving the object.
But it is not pre-populating the formset (only the form). Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Jaacob looks like I missed `request.POST` part here: `formset = IngredientModelFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)`. Also do you use inlineformset_factory now?

Comment: yes i changed to inlineformset_factory. 
It seems like it will save but not populate when i use: formset = IngredientModelFormset(queryset=Ingredient.objects.none(), instance=instance) 

And it will populate but not save when I use: IngredientModelFormset(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)

Comment: @Jaacob that's weird. Can you add updated code to your question?

Comment: I have updated the question now - I now the issue is slightly new, but it would be great if you had any suggestions. Thanks a lot!